# How to upload a PyPI package to Nexus3

Tags: python, nexus, pypi, nexus3, twine

I am new to Nexus3, I am following the instruction here to upload a PyPI package (python v2.7): https://books.sonatype.com/nexus-book/3.0/reference/pypi.html 
However, I got the following message prevent me from uploading the the package.

> HTTPError: 401 Client Error: Unauthorized for url

I did the following steps and not sure if I missed anything:
1. Setup blob and repo name in Nexus3
2. Copy the url to .pypirc
3. `python setup.py sdist; twine upload -r nexus3 dist/[secure]-0.1.0.tar.gz`

Please suggest, Thanks!

Comment: which nexus version are you using exactly?

Comment: Are you using admin/admin123?  If so is admin enabled?  If not, I'd recheck your username/password in your pypirc.  401 indicates it's wrong.  I'd ask to see it but if you're not using admin/admin123, it's probably sensitive and I wouldn't be able to tell anyway.  Here's mine if it helps: cat .pypirc
[distutils]
index-servers =
    nexus

[nexus]
repository: http://localhost:8081/repository/pypi-hosted/
username: admin
password: admin123

Comment: @Chengzhi have you tried without .pypirc config ?
you can tell twine to which server, worked for me. try - 
twine upload --repository-url http://<nexus>repository/<Repo-name>/ dist/*

Answer (score 3):

I had to add `--config-file .pypirc` to `twine upload`.

So

```
twine upload --config-file .pypirc -r nexus3 dist/[secure]-0.1.0.tar.gz
```